# What is the proper replacement igniter for my York furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace

I replaced one of these before on another unit but the part number was printed on the igniter.

This one is not so, being ignorant to HVAC I just want to make sure I get the appropriate part.

York Stellar Model: M3UF044SA

I pulled the igniter and it looks just like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FH7R298) but there is no model number on it so I just want to be sure.

Are most of these universal?

[image: igniter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot surface igniters are fairly universal it they look the same and have the same voltage. For example the igniters on this side of the pond they are usually 120v so depending on your area yours may be a 230/240v. I have had some bad luck with after market igniters coming cracked or with a fingerprint on the igniter in a sealed bag. 
Make sure not to touch the element any body oils like a finger print can cause a very short service life. 
Since you have some room the one you reference if the correct voltage should work if it looks the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reassurance! I ordered the part.